# Is there any way to select first row of filtered(visible) entries and store it's row number into a cell via script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've a google sheets table in range `A22:T2000`, with header at row 22
When it filtered (By a criteria of C column - Image),

1. How to select first row (visible) and store it's row_number into cell A1.
   (row 515 - image)
2. How to move to the next visible row
   It must done in one sheet named "Entri_Meter"

My plan is to use OFFSET function to get the data place in a row above the table (Row 21) and set to print area (`C1:H20`). OFFSET function require "Row Number". Thank you for any help.

[image]

I'm newbie in Google App Script
From Excel VBA, now learning Google Sheet App Script

Comment: About your 2 questions `1. How to select first row (visible) and store it's row_number into cell A1. (row 515 - image)` and `2. How to move to the next visible row It must done in one sheet named "Entri_Meter"`, I think that [`isRowHiddenByFilter`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isRowHiddenByFilter(Integer)) might be able to be used.

Comment: But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `My plan is to use OFFSET function to get the data place in a row above the table (Row 21) and set to print area (C1:H20). OFFSET function require "Row Number".`. So, I cannot still propose a sample script. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: yes, sir. Mr Cooper had give me an example script that work. Actually I want to print record by record of filtered data using Offset formula, that require offset_row (row position for every each of filtered entries - visible row). I need that row number A1 cell .

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Unfiltered Row**

```
function firstrownotfiltered() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const hr = sh.getFilter().getRange().getRow();//gets row where filter starts
  const rg = sh.getRange(hr + 1, 1, sh.getLastRow() - hr);
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues();
  var vrow;
  for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    if (!sh.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + hr + 1)) {
      vrow = i + hr + 1;
      ss.toast(`First Row Not Filtered: ${vrow}`);
      return vrow;
    }
  }
}
```

- [Filter.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#getrange)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [Sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isrowhiddenbyuserrowposition)

Comment: It's work with two minutes execution (log). is there anyway to make it faster ?

Comment: Wow you must have hidden quite a few lines because in my case is ran in just a few seconds.  This is the first time I've ever done this so I don't really know another way.